# Do continuous effects stack?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Does [Kragma Warcaller](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Kragma%20Warcaller) **stack** with the **+2/+0**.
Lets say if i have a **2/3** Minotaur and I play 2 **Kragma Warcallers**- does that **2/3** Minotaur become a **6/3**?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? You have 2 abilities that each say that Minotaurs get +2/+0. If you had one Warcaller and a card that gives all of your creatures +1/+1, what do you think would happen?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. All continuous effects are applied at all times they are active. If a continuous effect grants +2/+0, it means it raises the creature's power by two. So if two continuous effects grant +2/+0 to a creature, the creature's power will be raised by 4.